# How to save elements in DB in several iterations?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There are 315 `webElement` in `allElement`. I have to save 9 element each on my database table. How could I do this?
I have tried

```
for (var i = 0; i<=find; i++)
{
    IList<IWebElement> allElement = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@class='TableText1'][2]/tbody/tr/td[contains(@class, 'Table_List') or contains(@class, 'Table_List_diff')]"));

    for (int j = 0; j < allElement.Count; j=j+9)
    {
        var list1 = allElement.Take(j+9).ToArray();
        try
        {
            var text = new access_event_logs();
            text.USERID = list1[0].Text;
            text.DEPARTMENT = list1[3].Text;
            text.LOCAL_TIMESTAMP = Convert.ToDateTime(list1[4].Text);
            text.EVENTID = list1[5].Text;
            text.TERMINALSN = list1[6].Text;
            text.PhotoPath = list1[7].Text;
            text.REMARKS = list1[8].Text;
            text.ACCESSMETHOD = "fp";
            text.TERMINALIP = "09898";
            text.PHOTO = null;
            text.PHOTOSIZE = 0;
            text.RECLOGFROMIP = "";

            db.access_event_logs.Add(text);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }    
    }
```

I could save only first 9 element [0]to [8].. how can I save all the 315 element?
I have an idea. First save 9 element and then remove these element from the list. But I couldn't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `Take()` docs in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx)

> An IEnumerable that contains the specified number of elements from the start of the input sequence.

In `allElement.Take(j+9)` you always take from the beginning of the list. Since you take always the first 9 elements from the returned list it will always give you the same elements. Try [GetRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead

```
var list1 = allElement.GetRange(j, 9).ToArray();
```

Please note `GetRande()` won't work on `IList`, only on `List`. Change `IList<IWebElement> allElement` to `List<IWebElement> allElement`

Comment: "cannt convert source type  to target type" error occurs to change IList<IWebElement> allElement to List<IWebElement> allElement

Comment: @Tamim add `.ToList()` to `driver.FindElements` `driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@class='TableText1'][2]/tbody/tr/td[contains(@class, 'Table_List') or contains(@class, 'Table_List_diff')]")).ToList();`